# Add extra number beside array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want setting an array and below is my code

```
    public static void setArray()
{
    int i = 5;
    int j = 5;
    int testarray[][] = new  int[i][j];

    for(int x = 0;x<i;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<j;y++)
        {
            System.out.print("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println("");     
    } 
}
```

the result is something like this: 
0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

if i want to put a number/alphabet beside to let the user know which column, how can i do that ?

Expected Result:

====================

1 2 3 4 5

A|0 0 0 0 0

B|0 0 0 0 0

C|0 0 0 0 0

D|0 0 0 0 0

E|0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 2):

You need another initial for-loop to print the numbers, then you need to add another print statement within your second for-loop to print the letter for each row:

```
System.out.print(" ");
for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {  // this prints the numbers on the first row
    System.out.print(" " + x);
}
System.out.println();

for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
    System.out.print((char) ('A' + x) + "|");  // this prints the letters
    for (int y = 0; y < j; y++) {
        System.out.print("0 ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

```
  0 1 2 3 4
A|0 0 0 0 0 
B|0 0 0 0 0 
C|0 0 0 0 0 
D|0 0 0 0 0 
E|0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .. `column` number of times and print A, B, C, D .. till you reach the number of `row`s. Try coding it yourself, it's not that difficult (I don't want to provide a ready-made code)